# Close distant USSD session

Tags: ussd

I am working on a USSD client. Everything works fine except for closing a distant USSD session.

In the specification, we can see the function CUSD:
AT+CUSD=2 should close the USSD session, but this is not really the case.

In fact when I do this sequence:

```
AT+CUSD='#xxx#',12
AT+CUSD='1',12
```

I have an open distant connection.
On your handset, you can open a new session by dialing #xxx*#

If I send a:

```
 AT+CUSD='#xxx*#',12
```

This is not opening a new distant session.
If I send a:

```
AT+CUSD=2
AT+CUSD='#xxx#'
```

This is not opening a new distant session.

Do you know how to close a distant session?
I am working with huwaei key E160 and E173 on windows or Linux.

Comment: Which specification are you referring to? ETSI specs or Huawei's manual? The `AT+CUSD=2` is the correct command to close a USSD session. Note that there's a time limit on each session and you might want to add a delay after issuing a close session command. When sending a code to initiate a session, the *DCS* can be limited by the modem and some may accept only specific value. In my experience, it can be either `0` or `15` (from *Siemens* and *ZTE* modems). Also, if the signal strength is too low, it may cause unstable session state. So it's recommended to enable the result code.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I use the ETSI specs. In fact, I think that you are true on this point: It should be a time limit between each session on USSD server or on USSD Key. I will check this point in the Huawei's manual. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use in the following way.
AT+CUSD='#xxx#',15
AT+CUSD=2

Answer (score 0):

I am posting this because this is the top result regarding terminating USSD sessions using AT commands and also because the answers are vague.
This is the c# code i used in the end(I was sending the commands to a gsm modem). Hope it helps someone else

```
    SerialPort SendingPort=null;

    public string TerminateUssdSession()
    {
            InitializePort();

            //// generate terminate command for modem
            string cmd = "";
            cmd = "AT+CUSD=2\r";

            // send cmd to modem
            OpenPort();

            SendingPort.Write(cmd);

            Thread.Sleep(500);

            string response = SendingPort.ReadExisting();

            return response;

    }

    private void InitializePort()
    {
        if (SendingPort == null)
        {
            SendingPort = new SerialPort();
            SendingPort.PortName = PortName;//put portname here e.g COM5
            SendingPort.BaudRate = "112500";
            SendingPort.Parity = Parity.None;
            SendingPort.DataBits = 8;
            SendingPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            SendingPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
            SendingPort.ReadTimeout = 500;
        }
    }

    private void OpenPort()
    {
        if (!SendingPort.IsOpen)
        {
            SendingPort.Open();
        }
    }
```